# IIS 10 URL redirect from one domain to another

Tags: redirect, url-rewriting, iis-10, url-rewrite-module

I would like to redirect a specific site from one domain to another and i have tried the following URL redirect. Not sure where i am going wrong.

I have an app at http://www.a.b.com/myapp/index.aspx

I would like to redirect it to 
http://www.a.c.com/myapp/index.aspx

```
<rule name="testredirect" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^myapp/index.aspx$" />
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.a.c.com/{R:0}" />
    <conditions>
          <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www.a.b.com$" />
    </conditions>
</rule>
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules See what FRT can tell.

Answer (score 0):

The rule work perfectly on my side. Please try to clean browser cache and post your detailed error message. Please ensure you are running the rule in the right place and has been enabled.

Besides, please check whether the incoming request is reaching the correct application pool.