# How to set multiple redirection rules on IIS 10

Tags: windows, redirect, iis, windows-server-2016, iis-10

I'm having an issue when trying to configure redirections on IIS server. I have a website running in IIS and first of all i'd like to:

- redirect all the incoming requests for that site from http->https
- redirect all the incoming requests for that site if the URL is for example: https: //abc.org to https ://abc.org/loginpage

I set the first rule as explained here: https://www.ssl.com/how-to/redirect-http-to-https-with-windows-iis-10/

And then set the second rule as explained here: [IIS 10 URL redirect from one domain to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62325854/iis-10-url-redirect-from-one-domain-to-another)

But it's still not working. Tried restarting IIS, restarting app pools, website, clearing browser cache...
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use this URL Rewrite rule:

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Test" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
        <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO}" pattern="^http$" ignoreCase="false" />
         </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://example.com/loginpage" redirectType="Found" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

You need to modify example.com to abc.org.

Comment: I did exactly as you said and it's not working. Only opening the abc.org page

Comment: I suggest you clear your browser cache first. You can also use FRT to view the redirected URL: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis